# Splitting more that one column with delimter to multiple columns in python at once

Tags: python, pandas

I have a below dataframe

[image]

I want to split this based on a delimiter '\n' so that the output should look something like this
[image]

Would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried to split one column at a time by using

df[1].str.split(' ', 1, expand=True)...but getting an error for the same.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) in list comprehension with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df[x].str.split(expand=True) for x in df.columns], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
print (df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['07\n08','18.2\n17'],'B':['09\n10','11\n12'], 'C':['12\n12','11\n22.2']})
```

join the columns adding \n between the join

```
df['new'] = df.apply('\n'.join, axis=1)
```

Drop all the initial columnns

```
 df.drop(columns=['A','B','C'], inplace=True)
df
```

Split on \n to get new columns

```
 df.new.str.split(r'\n', expand=True)
```

Comment: Good to know. Obviously, @jezrael is a superior answer from lots of experience